# AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'pencolour'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and have the following code:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Pen()    
t.speed(0)
colours = ["green", "blue", "dark purple", "grey"]

for x in range(100):
    t.pencolour( colours[ x % 4] )
    t.cirlce(2*x)
    t.left(91)
```

If I try to run this code, I'm getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'pencolour'

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.pencolor), it's `.pencolor()`, not `.pencolour()`.

This means that you should write:

```
t.pencolor( colours[ x % 4] )
```

instead of

```
t.pencolour( colours[ x % 4] )
```

[Attribute errors](http://cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/1213/pylearn/final_results/encyclopedia/attributeError.html) in Python are generally raised when you try to access or call an attribute that a particular object type doesn’t possess.
In your example, you are calling the method `pencolour`, but the implemented one is called `pencolor`